# Graphical multiple file-pair comparison on Mac OS 10.7

Tags: macos, svn, diff

Is it possible to view "svn diff" output graphically on Mac OS?

Most of the graphical diff programs allow you to view only one file per time. Which is very inconvenient when you use svn and have changed like 10 files.

For Linux I have found a solution in "[kompare](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/kompare-a-tool-of-beauty/)" program.
I do:

```
svn diff > diffOut; kompare diffOut
```

and as result I work with graphical program and check all files at once like it shown on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soFmh.jpg).

**Is there same thing for Mac OS?**

P.S. "meld" programm seems to do the same (or it doesn't?), and I have already tried to install it, but got an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892957/meld-on-os-x-10-7-doesnt-work). Therefore I supouse that I can't install it under OSx 10.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is kompare for Mac OS. 
   It is a part of KDE SDK and one can get it using MacPorts:

   ```
   sudo port install kdesdk4
   launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
   export PATH="/Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/kompare.app/Contents/MacOS:"$PATH
   ```

   and it works!
2. Svn supports so called [external diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.diff.ex-1).

To use it one should create svn-wrapper script, which will take parameters returned by "svn diff" command and call differ with required parameters.

here is an example of parameters "svn diff" returns:

```
-u -L code/Class1.h (revision 16518) -L code/Class1.h (working copy) code/.svn/text-base/Class1.h.svn-base code/Class1.h
```

opendiff needs last two. Therefore next bash [script](http://code.google.com/p/svntree-bench/source/browse/trunk/contrib/client-side/diff-wrap.sh?r=1) will be appropriate:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 [ignored args...] file1 file2" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# The last two arguments passed to this script are the paths to the files
# to diff.
while [ $# -gt 2 ]; do
    shift
done

exec opendiff $*
```

put this script in svnwrapper.sh file. Made file executable:

```
chmod +x svnwrapper.sh
```

and put it in some common path, which is added to $PATH variable.
Now you can call svn using

```
svn diff --diff-cmd=svnwrapper.sh
```

or just add at the section [helpers] in ~/.subversion/config file:

```
diff-cmd = svnwrapper.sh
```

Comment: In Mavericks i get No ksycoca4 database available!

Answer (score 64):

You could use Apple's [FileMerge](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/features.html) tool, or [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com). Both of these have command-line invocations:

- to open FileMerge, install the command-line developer tools from inside Xcode and use `opendiff`
- to open Kaleidoscope, install its command-line tools from inside Kaleidoscope and use `ksdiff`

Comment: Ok. Then could you help me to find FileMerge? I understood it is part of Xcode. I have Xcode installed, but spotlight can not find FileMerge, as well thereisn't any command like this in Terminal.

Comment: I've adapted my answer, but a Google search for "command line filemerge" will tell you what you need.

Comment: opendiff is FileMerge?? I've tried it: 1. it cann't open diffOutput file, 2. with "svn diff --diff-cmd opendiff" I get:
Index: code/***.cxx
===================================================================
2012-08-07 14:44:16.146 opendiff[36627:e07] ***/work/-u does not exist

Comment: I grant you +50, since you the only one, who recommended multi file-pair comparison program, which can work from command line. Even though you didn't told this to me and I get this information accidentally. I'm talking about Kaleidoscope, which have svn wrapper and can be used as svn diff --diff-cmd=ksdiff-svnwrapper, resulting exatly to what I wanted to get. Pity that it is not free:(

Comment: Looking properly this is where i ended up, found this in addition. http://www.defraine.net/~brunod/fmdiff/

Comment: I ran across this thread and tried Apple's FileMerge tool. It got the job done, had a clean, native OS X UI and it's free. I think that's a winning combination (at least for me).

Comment: $70 for a diff tool seems a bit steep to me.

Comment: omg, opendiff is so slow if you call it multiple times in a row( I mean like `opendiff file1 file2; opendiff file3 file4`.

Answer (score 9):

[KDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) is an open source , visual text difference program. You can use it in windows,unix, linux and Mac OSX . Give it try. On windows , it automatically adds itself for svn diff. I do not use Mac OSX therefore can not say this function is also available there.

> compares or merges two or three text input files or directories,

Following [image url](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/dirmergebig.png) from kdiff3 site shows that it compare directories.

Comment: It does not do MULTIPLE file comparison, only one at the time. Which is very inconvenient for me. If I wrong, please, tell me more details about hot to use it in svn in the way similar to the way I used "kompare".

Comment: @klm123: Current version (0.9.97) can comapre three folders at a time. I'm not sure wether this is what you are looking for.

Comment: the interface is messy and not intuitive :/

Comment: The program is slow and clumsy. It has problems even with small files. Not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

[DiffMerge](http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) is both free and great. Also does 3 way comparison and merging.

Comment: I've been using DiffMerge, it is cool, but you can only merge from left to right, to merge from right to left you have to open the two folders in reverse order

Comment: yep, but kdiff3 interface is messy, I dont understand how to use

Answer (score 2):

[Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) is a really good choice if you want to switch fast from comparing directory structures and files in directories. It is also possible to compare more then 2 copies. I have also impression that the algorithm to compare files (match blocks and colorcode changes) is really good. At the end, a 15 day trial is available, than you need to pay.

Comment: Well, I bought it and I am happy user so I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if i've understood correctly, however i use Eclipse with subclipse plugin on a mac.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx

Make sure you read the page to get the correct version and also take into account the version of svn your using.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=1BCECCE84434FF08FDE32136D13FF061?pageID=p4wYuA

When installed you can then select the syncronisation perspective, view all files that are conflicted and require changing.

I'm not sure however if it will let your say diff random files, which i think your sort of asking. You could try it however.

Comment: Can it be used as "svn diff | eclipse" or as "svn diff --diff-cmd=eclipse" with result shown on the picture in the post?

Comment: Command line no, sorry. Its a full IDE with subversion integration. The sync view shows files with differences, conflicts etc in a tree view. You can then edit a specific file to get the same type of affair in your picture. Basically you wouldn't need the command line. You simply right click the file in the file explorer and click "compare with" > revision, or "latest from repos" select the revision and you then get the diff view.

Comment: Sorry, I don't need full IDE.

Comment: no problem, added a link to Grahams Answer as thats what i found when i checked for cmd line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187064/graphical-diff-for-mac-os-x Also covers a lot of other answers to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice file-file diff tool.
P4Merge: http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools

Answer (score 0):

Bruno De Fraine wrote some scripts that launch OSX's FileMerge for each file: http://www.defraine.net/~brunod/fmdiff/

Install

```
> svn co http://soft.vub.ac.be/svn-gen/bdefrain/fmscripts/ fmscripts
> cd fmscripts
> make
> sudo make install
```

Diff (launch FileMerge for each file)

```
> svn diff --diff-cmd fmdiff
```

Answer (score 0):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) isn't free, but I've used it and liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the latest version of [Meld for OSX](https://yousseb.github.io/meld/) `.dmg` installer.

Answer (score -2):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is another one you can add to the list. It's free & cross-platform (Windows, Mac, Linux).